# Error using value as jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm passing an array `idArray` to a jQuery each function, which I'm then using to get the values. I'm trying to use the values to create a new jQuery selector.

Here's what an example idArray looks like:

```
Array[4]
0 : "5"
1 : "6"
2 : "8"
3 : "9"
```

Here's my code:

```
function editGigs(idArray) {
    console.log(idArray); // Produces array correctly
    $(idArray).each(function(k, v) {
        trId = "'#row" + v + "'";
        console.log(trId); // Produces '#row5'
        $(trId).find('.td.forename').css('background-color', 'black');
    });
}
```

I'm getting an error, as follows:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#row5'
```

However, when I add '#row5' into the last line of the code itself as the id selector, it works...?! Something appears to be wrong in the way I'm using a value from the jQuery each function as the id selector.

Comment: Remove the single quotes -> `trId = "#row" + v;`

Comment: Also `$(idArray)` isn't a great idea as jQuery is expecting an array of DOMElements, not strings. You could use `idArray.forEach()`, or a simple `for` loop instead

Comment: Thanks @Andreas - that works... why is it necessary to remove the single quotes?

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan - that's useful. I was thinking that there might be a better way. Will try these.

Comment: Because `'#row5'` (with the quotes) is not a valid selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use single quotes `''` in the selector :

```
trId = "'#row" + v + "'";
```

Should be :

```
trId = "#row" + v;
```

Since the string has already double quotes `""` by default, so when you add the single ones the result is an invalid selector looks like :

```
$("'#rowV'")
```

Hope this helps.